# How come a small dataset has a high variance?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Why does a small dataset have a high variance? Our professor once said it. I just did not understand it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single one of us, by the time we are entering our professional careers, have been exposed to a larger visual dataset then the largest dataset available for AI researchers. On top of this, we have sound, smell, touch, and taste data all coming in from our external senses. In summary, humans have a lot of context on the human world. We have a general common-sense understanding of human situations. When analyzing a dataset, we combine the data itself with our past knowledge in order to come up with an analysis.

The typical machine learning algorithm has none of that — it has only the data you show to it, and that data must be in a standardized format. If a pattern isn’t present in the data, there is no way for the algorithm to learn it. That's why when given a small dataset it is more prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

if your data set is small and you train your model to fit the data set ,it is easy to have overfitting problems.If your data set is big enough,a little overfitting may not a big problem ,but not in a small data set.